# VC++ "Re-use" a function?

Tags: c++

How can I re-use a function?

Okay lets say I have this "main" function below:

```
bool A = false;
bool B = true;
void MainFunction(bool Whatever) {
    if(!Whatever) {
        A = true;
        if(A) {
            B = false;
        } else if(!A) {
            B = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a new function using the MainFunction, something like this:

```
MainFunction ANewFunction(false);
MainFunction AnotherNewFunction(true);
```

Obviously that won't work, so is there any way to "re-use" a function as a different function?

Comment: If the new function does more work along with the previous functions work, call the previous function in the new function. Not too sure what you want to achieve, maybe you can re-check your code design.

Comment: Well that is actually the function that I am using. I was just wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef int (*function_t)(int); // new type - defines function type - address of function 


// your function, PrevFunction is simply variable holding address of the function:
int PrevFunction(int one) { return one; }

// new variable of type function_t initialized by PrevFunction address: 
function_t NewFunction = PrevFunction;

//And finally we can use either PrevFunction or NewFunction - they point to the same function body: 

int a = PrevFunction(1); // a == 1
int b = NewFunction(2); // a == 2
```

Comment: Well not exactly what I was looking for, but hey I've learned something from this piece of code :) ty.

Comment: Just realized that you just need these two aliases:
`#define ANewFunction MainFunction(false)` and
`#define AnotherNewFunction MainFunction(true)`

Answer (score 4):

You're welcome to have one function call another. For example:

```
void ANewFunction() {
  MainFunction(false);
}
void AnotherNewFunction() {
  MainFunction(true);
}
```

You can even get fancy:

```
#include <functional>
auto ANewFunction = std::bind(&MainFunction, false);
auto AnotherNewFunction = std::bind(&MainFunction, true);
```

Either way, you can call `ANewFunction` or `AnotherNewFunction`, and `MainFunction` will get called with the given argument. (In the latter case, they're not really functions anymore. They're called function objects, or *functors*, but you cal still call them just like ordinary functions: `ANewFunction()`.)

Comment: `bind` is precisely what answers the question. This should be accepted!

Answer (score 1):

You can't "re-use" functions, at least not in the way I understand your question.

But you can create a new function that calls the original function and then does some additional work of its own. For example:

```
void PrevFunction(int one)
{
    int i = one;
    // do whatever
}

void NewFunction(int one)
{
    PrevFunction(one);

    // do new stuff
    // ...
}
```

You could also define a class, and then use inheritance and `virtual` functions to modify the behavior of a particular set of functions from the base class.

Comment: But the problem is that the PrevFunction has a boolean. Would creating another NewFunction effect the boolean?

Comment: Cause my goal is basically to like make a new copy of the PrevFunction and I don't want to re-code the PrevFunction for each function that is exactly doing the same thing.

Comment: @Bawss: I'm not really sure what you mean by "has a boolean". Edit your question to include some actual sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call MainFunction from your other function?

```
void ANewFunction()
{
    MainFunction(false);
}
void AnotherNewFunction()
{
    MainFunction(true);
}
```

If your question is how do you make AnotherNewFunction refer to a different A and B than ANewFunction, the answer is you can't, at least not without help from MainFunction. You can, however, update MainFunction:

```
void MainFunction(bool Whatever, bool& A, bool& B) {
    if(!Whatever) {
        A = true;
        if(A) {
            B = false;
        } else if(!A) {
            B = true;
        }
    }
}
bool A1 = false;
bool B1 = true;
void ANewFunction()
{
    MainFunction(false, A1, B1);
}
bool A2 = false;
bool B2 = true;
void AnotherNewFunction()
{
    MainFunction(true, A2, B2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another new-fangled solution, using *lambda's*:

```
auto ANewFunction = [](){ MainFunction(false); }
auto AnotherNewFunction = [](){ MainFunction(true); }
```